# Jython word frequency counter

Tags: python, jython, jes

So I need help just removing the extra words for this one part, this is an edit cause I've made some progress since originally posted, but any help would be appreciated.

I'm making sublists inside the list wordList for each name, and counting their frequency and storing the word and their frequency in the sublist.
This is the output I am getting:

[['Kylie', 3], ['Kylie', 3], ['Kylie', 3], ['Abigail', 2], ['Abigail', 2], ['Louise', 1], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Debbie', 2], ['Debbie', 2]]

What I want is:

[['Kylie', 3], ['Abigail', 2], ['Louise', 1], ['Cynthia', 6], ['Debbie', 2]]

```
def readText():
filename = pickAFile()
file = open(filename, "rt")
readWord = file.read().split()
wordList = []
for word in readWord:
  if word not in wordList: 
    wordList.append([word,readWord.count(word)])

print wordList

file.close()
```

Comment: At least three things are weird here: (1) your choice of a `list` over a `dict` for your word-frequency counters, (2) the `if word not in wordList` test will always be `True`, and (3) the fact that you count all the instances of the word each time you encounter a single instance of the word.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Please use a `collections.Counter` if you're on Jython 2.7. If you're on an older version of Jython, use a backport/recipe for `Counter` so you can update your code by replacing just the import. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter